# Delete blank columns from header row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to python and I'm having trouble deleting the header columns after the 25th column. There are 8 more extra columns that have no data so I'm trying to delete those columns. Columns 1-25 have like 50,000k of data and the rest of the columns are blank.How would I do this? My code for now is able to clean up the file but I cant delete the headers for row[0] AFTER COLUMN 25.
Thanks

```
import csv

my_file_name = "NVG.txt"
cleaned_file = "cleanNVG.csv"
remove_words = ['INAC-EIM','-INAC','TO-INAC','TO_INAC','SHIP_TO-inac','SHIP_TOINAC']


with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile, open(cleaned_file, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    cr =  csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerow(next(cr)) #I think this is why is not working
    for line in (r[0:25] for r in cr):
        #del line [26:32]
        if not any(remove_word in element for element in line for remove_word in remove_words):
        line[11]= line[11][:5]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've found the line with the problem - all you have to do is only print the headers you want.  `next(cr)` reads the header line, but you pass the entire line to `writer.writerow()`.

Instead of

```
writer.writerow(next(cr))
```

you want:

```
writer.writerow(next(cr)[:25])
```

(`[:25]` and `[0:25]` are the same in Python)

Comment: Wow I had this before and it threw an error and it was cause one of the lines had an indentation error so I thought it was something else. Thanks!! This worked :)